# how can i apply the textarea design same as input text field

Tags: html, css

html,

```
<input type="text"/>
<textarea></textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kAWDd/

very simple code

if i print, this two have different default design.

i tried `border:1px solid black` like this, but still it has different design

i want it to be same.

what kind of css do i have to apply?

Any good Solution?

=============

um sorry for the bad question :( I want to copy the default text input field design to the

text area. but the answers in here is applying textarea design to text input field

Comment: `default design`...you mean dimensions or something else??

Comment: So you have an apple and an orange, and you want them to look like a lemon...

Comment: create a common css style and apply to both text and textarea

Comment: Crete common css class and apply that class to both textbox and textarea.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/kAWDd/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/kAWDd/10/

*Markup*:

```
<input type="text"/>
<textarea rows="1"></textarea>
```

*CSS*:

```
input, textarea {
    height: 24px; width: 64px;
    line-height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    resize: none;
}
```

*Footnote*: Bad idea!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution,don't worry :)

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/kAWDd/11/

```
input[type=text],textarea{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    padding:10px;
    background:#adcff5;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: +1 : but you might wanna mention to `clear:both` to OP too!! :)

Comment: if you want clear,then add clear porperty like this :- clear:left/right;

Answer (score 0):

[See this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAWDd/8/)..you want something like this??

```
.input_box{
  border: 1px solid black;

}
textarea{
  resize: none;
  height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Refer [@Nikhil's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21042910/1542290) answer